# IE not interpreting mod_rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a ***really*** simple `mod_rewrite` rule:

```
<Directory "/local/foobar.com/">
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^test$ hello/ [R]
</Directory>
```

In Chrome, when I go to `www.foobar.com/test`, I get redirected to `www.foobar.com/hello/`, but in IE9, no redirection happens - what am I missing?!

**Further info**

As requested in a comment, log output:

Chrome:

```
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420002978/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] strip per-dir prefix: /local/foo.com/test -> test
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420002978/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] applying pattern '^test$' to uri 'test'
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420002978/initial] (2) [perdir /local/foo.com/] rewrite 'test' -> 'hello/'
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420002978/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] add per-dir prefix: hello/ -> /local/foo.com/hello/
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420002978/initial] (2) [perdir /local/foo.com/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://foo.com/local/foo.com/hello/
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420002978/initial] (2) [perdir /local/foo.com/] trying to replace prefix /local/foo.com/ with /
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420002978/initial] (1) [perdir /local/foo.com/] escaping http://foo.com/hello/ for redirect
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420002978/initial] (1) [perdir /local/foo.com/] redirect to http://foo.com/hello/ [REDIRECT/302]
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420006998/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] add path info postfix: /local/foo.com/hello -> /local/foo.com/hello/
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420006998/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] strip per-dir prefix: /local/foo.com/hello/ -> hello/
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420006998/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] applying pattern '^test$' to uri 'hello/'
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:17:56:39 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f4420006998/initial] (1) [perdir /local/foo.com/] pass through /local/foo.com/hello
```

IE9:

```
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f440c00a9b8/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] strip per-dir prefix: /local/foo.com/test -> test
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f440c00a9b8/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] applying pattern '^test$' to uri 'test'
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f440c00a9b8/initial] (2) [perdir /local/foo.com/] rewrite 'test' -> 'hello/'
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f440c00a9b8/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] add per-dir prefix: hello/ -> /local/foo.com/hello/
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f440c00a9b8/initial] (2) [perdir /local/foo.com/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://foo.com/local/foo.com/hello/
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f440c00a9b8/initial] (2) [perdir /local/foo.com/] trying to replace prefix /local/foo.com/ with /
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f440c00a9b8/initial] (1) [perdir /local/foo.com/] escaping http://foo.com/hello/ for redirect
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f440c00a9b8/initial] (1) [perdir /local/foo.com/] redirect to http://foo.com/hello/ [REDIRECT/302]
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f44101b7688/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] add path info postfix: /local/foo.com/hello -> /local/foo.com/hello/
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f44101b7688/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] strip per-dir prefix: /local/foo.com/hello/ -> hello/
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f44101b7688/initial] (3) [perdir /local/foo.com/] applying pattern '^test$' to uri 'hello/'
192.171.135.86 - - [16/Nov/2015:18:01:45 +0000] [foo.com/sid#7f4458ffddc8][rid#7f44101b7688/initial] (1) [perdir /local/foo.com/] pass through /local/foo.com/hello
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Apache based on the config snippet.  What version are you running and have you tried enabling the rewrite log to get some extra info on what's going on?

Comment: @DavidKing Oops - sorry, yes - I am using Apache: `apachectl -v` returns `Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)` - I haven't enabled the rewrite log (I didn't even know about it...)

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog will get you the info you need.  Essentially you need to add `RewriteLog /path/to/log/file.log` and `RewriteLogLevel 3`.  Just be warned...if this is a high volume server it will generate a LOT of output.

Comment: @DavidKing Hmm, I've got a log file generated now :) - the output from a Chrome request looks exactly the same as an IE request!

Comment: Can you post the log entries from each?  My guess is that it's related to the specific HTTP code that Apache is using to send the redirect.  You may need to change the `[R]` to be something like `[R,L=301]` to force Apache to use a code that IE9 will recognize.

Comment: I was a bit reluctant to use 301 because of the apparent _feature_ in IE9 that makes a 301 so permanent it persists after clearing history and cache (http://agsci.psu.edu/it/how-to/topics/web/plone/other/internet-explorer-9-permanently-caches-redirects)! Is a 302 likely to help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31665/discussion-between-david-king-and-chrisw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually realised what was happening.  I didn't actually have a folder called `hello` - I just wanted to test an abstract `mod_rewrite` rule.  It seems that Chrome will follow redirects regardless of any http codes that are returned, but that IE won't show the redirect if a 404 is subsequently returned.

Once I added a folder called `hello`, IE **did** follow the rule.